# Indy IdMessageBuilder attachments from memory

Tags: delphi-xe7, indy10

Is there a way that one can add a related attachment from memory instead of a file saved on disk using Indy's MessageBuilder?

I am adding a footer signature to my emails and the image is saved as a blob field in a database.

I can do this with IdMessage but MessageBuilder just makes everything so easier.

I am using Delphi XE7 and Indy 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` has a public `Data: TStream` property, and `TIdMessageBuilderAttachments` has an overloaded `Add()` method with an `AData: TStream` parameter.

If a `TStream` is used for an attachment's data, the builder creates a `TIdAttachmentMemory` and copies the stream data into it.  Otherwise, the builder creates a `TIdAttachmentFile` and assigns the specified filename to it.

So, you can obtain a `TStream` for your blob data, such as from `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()`, and create an email attachment from that.

Comment: I have populated a TStream and used this in the HtmlText.Add. The problem I have is that the image (logo) is not displayed as part of the email but added as a physical attachment with a .dat extension. Html.Text := tbEPendNote.Value + '<P><IMG border=0 hspace=0 alt="" src="cid:1234"></P>';
          Stream1 := qEmpl.CreateBlobStream(qEmplImage,bmRead);
          HtmlFiles.Add(Stream1,'1234');
          FillMessage(MSG);
        finally
          Stream1.Free;
          Free;
        end;

Comment: @Gerhard you are not calling `Add()` correctly. Double check the parameters. The `Add()` overload for `TStream` has 3 parameters, the overload for files has 2. You are passing `'1234'` in the `AContentType` parameter, not in the `AContentID` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Remy. My emails now looks professional after using Indy for many years